# Dnsmasq DHCP not giving IP address

Tags: networking, pi-2, dhcp

I have bought a RPI 2 for my 3D printer. My purpose is to access it remotely via wifi. I don't have a router, so I have created an Access Point on the RPI. I have also installed dnsmasq as the DHCP server.

Everything is working... except the DHCP service ! I can connect without any problem to my RPI only if I manually give an IP address to my computer

I have tried lots of different parameters for dnsmasq without success. I have listed my "final" configuration files. **Do you have an idea what is wrong ?**

```
/etc/network/interfaces

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

_

```
/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

interface=wlan0
driver=rtl871xdrv
ssid=RPI_Octoprint
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=1
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

And at the end of the following file, I have added:
(not sure that dhcp option 3 and 6 are useful...)

```
/etc/dnsmasq.conf

expand-hosts
interface=wlan0
dhcp-autoritative
dhcp-range=192.168.1.2,192.168.1.20,12h
dhcp-range=1,255.255.255.0
dhcp-range=3,192.168.1.1
dhcp-range=6,192.168.1.1
```

And I have also added (not sure what it is doing):

```
/etc/hosts
192.168.1.1 main
```

Thank you ! :)

Comment: Hello have you managed to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is most likely a dead post, but I stumbled upon it while looking for an answer to my issue and noticed the following straight off...

The issue appears to be that the OP missed this in the /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
dhcp-autoritative
```

which should have read:

```
dhcp-authoritative
```

Comment: Imho that's a simple typo, because OP has other typos such as the interface name `wlan` instead of `wlan0` in the `/etc/network/interface` config.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need is a single `dhcp-range=192.168.1.2,192.168.1.20,12h` line for the range. `dnsmasq` has a lot of additional options ranges for conditional ranges, but for a simple scenario like you've described, the single line should suffice.

If you're just appending lines to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, make sure there aren't spurious entries above. The default raspbian file has a lot of helpful information, but there's so much in there it's easy to double-up on entries. You might want to create a clean version with only your lines in it.

dhcp-options are specified with `dhcp-option` lines. I use them to specify default gateway, WINS server, default domain and the like.

Try changing these 3 lines:

```
dhcp-range=1,255.255.255.0
dhcp-range=3,192.168.1.1
dhcp-range=6,192.168.1.1
```

into dhcp-options.

```
# subnet mask
dhcp-option=1,255.255.255.0
# gateway
dhcp-option=3,192.168.1.1
# dns
dhcp-option=6,192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and to have pointed out my mistake ! I have tried with the corrected dhcp-option line and without and it is still not working. I have also cleaned the dnsmasq.conf file.
On my computer, when I try to connect to the RPI, I'm seeing: DHCP activated / Computer's IP: 169.254.224.62 / Mask: 255.255.255.0 and some IPV6 stuffs.
I have also observed that in my /etc/ folder, I have a dhcpcd.conf file which is empty and I think this file is related to the dhcp3 package. May be there is a conflict ?
Thank you.

Comment: Could it be as simple as dnsmasq not being enabled? Check the `/etc/default/dnsmasq` file and make sure it reads `ENABLED=1`.

Comment: The line is uncommented. I have tried to do `sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart` and I got `[FAIL] Restarting DNS forwarder and DHCP server: configuration syntax check failed!`. I had a look on internet and it is said to check `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`. Unfortunately, the dhcp3 folder is empty. Do I need to install dhcp3 package ? It seems weird. Thank you.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to install dhcp3. The error indicates a typo somewhere, so at least the problem makes sense. Can you sanitize the file and dump it in a pastebin perhaps? Did you fix those `dhcp-range` lines?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it. Here is my files. http://pastebin.com/91dMs2zh -> Configuration file of dnsmasq. // http://pastebin.com/AJth32wa -> Network configuration // http://pastebin.com/FNF0k81q -> This file is of particular interest as it is telling me that the configuration file has to be in this folder.... I have tried without success. I have also this file: http://pastebin.com/n83k6Z0P but I don't get it as I didn't install dhcpcd. May be my computer with W8.1 can't connect to a RPI... I will try with another computer as soon as possible.